# Set PDF Document Properties Initial View

Tags: acrobat, postscript

I am try to do set the Document Properties - > Initial View after creating PDF file from Post Script File.

Input PDF Initial View:

[image]

After my setting the Initial of the PDF file will as below:

[image]

This only I am trying to do by automation.

With the help of pdfmark Reference (Adobe SDK) I am tried to set **DOCVIEW** in post scrip

Post Script:

```
[ /PageMode /UseOutlines /Page 1 /View [/Fit] /DOCVIEW pdfmark
```

The above script will set

Document Properties - > Intial View

Document Option

- Show: Bookmarks Panel and Page

  Page Layout: Default

  Magnification: Fit Page

Window Options

- Show : File Name

---

But my expectation is as shown below,

---

Document Properties - > Intial View

Document Option

- Show: Bookmarks Panel and Page

  Page Layout: Continuous

  Magnification: Fit Width

Window Options

- List item

Show : Document Title

---

So please give me advice.

What is the post script for those things.

else any other way to set those by automation.

---

Regards

Thirusanguraja

Answer (score 2):

I am got the solution for my question, by the postscript only i am done this job

**Postscript Script:**

```
[ /PageMode /UseOutlines /View [/FitH -32768]/Page 1 /DOCVIEW pdfmark

[ {Catalog} <</ViewerPreferences<</DisplayDocTitle true>>/PageLayout/OneColumn>> /PUT pdfmark
```

Above postscript code was i am used to get my PDF Document Properties - > Initial View as

**Document Option**

- **Show:** Bookmarks Panel and Page

  **Page Layout:** Continuous

  **Magnification:** Fit Width

**Window Options**

- **Show :** Document Title

I hope my statement is true.

---

Regards,

Thirusanguraja Venkatesan

Answer (score 0):

There do not appear to be pdfmarks definitions to cover what you want (or at least I can't find them in the current pdfmark specification. That being the case you cannot create a PDF with those properties via pdfmark.

One of the features you want seems to be covered by the /DisplayDocTitle entry in a ViewerPreferences dictionary, but the rest I can't see anything obvious in the spec. I'm not convinced these are under control of the PDF but if they are, your best bet is to inspect one that does what you want.

Comment: Fine thank you, but am got solution lets see my answer and conform it